# Updating (refreshing) PHP variable without refreshing website

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make updating variable called $online without refreshing site.

Theres is my try:

**data.php**

```
<?php
    include("steam.php");
    $data =  $online;// obtain current value of data from somewhere
    echo $data; // should be an integer
?>
```

**refresh.js**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var data = []; // data is empty
    var graph = Morris.Bar({
      element: 'graph',
      data: data
      labels: ['random label']
    });

    function update () {
      $.getJSON( "data.php", function (newv) {
        data.push( { x: newv, y: "Today" } ); // store new value
        graph.setData( data );                // update the graph
      });
    }

    update();
    setInterval( update, 1000 );
  });
```

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. My initial thought is why care about the php variable? If you don't want to reload the page that variable will never be used since php is dead at the moment. I would skip php and load that into a javascript variable and then push that to php when you change the page.

Comment: It's too late, i have more variables in php so.. Is there any way to gain that?

Comment: Should be possible with [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Just skip down to sending along extra data. You're definitely on the right track. I've never done it, but I might put a little snippet together. On the other end just accept it like a normal post, `$online = $_POST['data'];`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this through so I know it works. My previous comment will do the job. I know $.getJSON is similar so I don't know what conflicts you will have there, but the below will update your php variable.

```
<script>
 $.post( "data.php", { online: "UpdatedData" } );
</script>
```

data.php

```
$online = $_POST['online'];
```